# Use chia seeds to help thicken a pot pie

Tags: pie, chia

Can I put chia seeds in a pot pie filling to help thicken it? If so, how would I do it? (i.e., how much chia seeds, how much cornstarch, do I need to pre-soak, etc.)

Edit: It was [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/16765/veggie-pot-pie/), and it was IMO quite runny with 2tbsp of corn starch.

Comment: Ok, I need to ask: why chia seeds?

Comment: @GdD They're (supposed to be) really healthy, and they don't taste like cornstarch.

Comment: I have no experience w/ chia seeds ... however for flax seeds, you grind them up first, then let them soak in the liquid for a bit before baking with them.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is answerable with this little information. We have no idea what is in your pot pie already, what consistency it is, etc. It would be best if you could post the recipe. Also, what do you expect? The viscosity will certainly go up, but the mouthfeel will be nothing like the one created by starch.

Comment: I know they're healthy and all, but wouldn't chia seeds add a strange texture to a pot pie?

Comment: I've read this question a couple of time while scanning through... And I am still yet to see a comment on how/if a chia seed compound would change the taste of the resulting gravy.

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is that a pie with 3 cups of liquid (750 ml) was runny with 2 tbsp of corn starch and some water sucking ingredients such as potatoes, *and* you say it tasted like corn starch, then you probably just didn't thicken the starch. You should try cooking the original recipe correctly before deciding whether to change it to something exotic.

Starch needs to be cooked to almost 100 Celsius to thicken. It is certainly above 90 for all types of starch. After thickening, it practically has no taste. Use a thermometer to ensure that it happened, 96 should be a good temperature to aim for.

You can probably thicken it with chia seeds instead of the starch, although I can't tell you the exact procedure and would like to see somebody posting an answer which explains how to do it. You might or might not like the result, which will be very different from a starch thickened pot pie.

Answer (score 1):

Chia seeds will thicken.  Soak over night , or if really in a hurry, pour very hot water over them and let them soak for 45 minutes.  They will jell somewhat and that's OK